# How do you read these kanji 年々?

Tags: word-choice, readings, reduplication

How do you guys read these kanji 年々 in a sentence? I've found on Japanese dictionary websites that it can be read both 'nen-nen' and 'toshi-doshi' and  it means 'year by year'. So which one use in a sentence by those mean?

Comment: What is the sentence?

Comment: I tried to fix up the English in this question, but "by those mean" doesn't mean anything to me, so I don't know what you were trying to ask when you wrote that.

Comment: @snailplane ok im sorry if my english is not good enough  Im still trying to ~.

Answer (score 7):

明鏡国語辞典 says としどし is a 名詞 and ねんねん is a 副詞.

> としどし【年年】〘名〙年を追うごと。年ごと。ねんねん。「ーーにさびれてきた祭事」

> ねんねん【年年】〘副〙年とともにだんだん。年ごとに。「ーー輸入が増加する」

So..

> How do you guys read these kanji 年々 in a sentence?

I'd read it as ねんねん when it's functioning as a 副詞(adverb) by itself, and as としどし when it's used as a 名詞(noun), followed by a case particle.

Comment: By the way, I think ねんねん is more common than としどし.

Comment: Oookay, so it has different function... Thank you for your answer!!!

Answer (score 6):

## 日本語

#### 年年{ねんねん} or 年々｛ねんねん｝

- 庭に植えた木は**年々{ねんねん}** 大きくなっています。
- 庭に植えたバラは**年々{ねんねん}** きれいな花を咲かせます。
  **年年{ねんねん}** あるいは **年々｛ねんねん｝** は、「毎年徐々に」、あるいは、「毎年のように」のように、毎年状態が一定である、あるいは一定の傾向であるような意味で扱う時に使う.

#### 年年｛としどし｝

- 庭に植えたバラは**年年{としどし}で**花の咲き具合が違います。　
  **年年｛としどし｝** は、各々の年が特徴ある個別のものであるとして扱う時に使う。

---

## EDIT

「年々｛ねんねん｝あるいは年々｛ねんねん｝」と「年年｛としどし｝」とは使っている漢字は同じですが、意味や用法がかなり違います。

- 「ねんねん」は、「毎年｛まいとし｝」あるいは「年が進｛すす｝むごとに」とほぼ似た意味をもっており、相互に置き換えても余り違和感がありません。また、「としどし」は、「[年毎]｛としごと｝」とほぼ似た意味を持っており、これも相互に置き換えても余り意味が変わらないように思います。
- Chocolateさんが紹介した辞書に書かれているとおり、「ねんねん」と「としどし」とは品詞が違います。「ねんねん」は副詞であり、文章の中でそのまま使えます。一方、「としどし」は名詞であり、「としどし**に**」、「としどし**で**」あるいは「としどし**の**」のように助詞を付けて初めて文章の中で使えます。品詞の違いおよび助詞の必要性については、類似の単語として上に挙げた「毎年｛まいとし｝」および「年毎｛としごと｝」についても同様のことが言えます。すなわち、「毎年{まいとし}」は副詞であり、そのまま文章の中で使えます。また、「年毎｛としごと｝」は「[年毎]｛としごと｝**に**」「[年毎]｛としごと｝**で**」あるいは「[年毎]｛としごと｝**の**」のように助詞を付けて初めて使えます。
- 上記辞書に記載されている意味を比べますと、「としどし」に助詞をつけて「としどしに」あるいは「としどしで」とすれば「ねんねん」と同様の意味の副詞となり、相互に置き換えられるように読み取れますが、普段使っている実際の用例で考えますと、私の最初の回答の例文にあるように文が持つ意味がかなり違うので実際には置き換えられないように思います。
  すなわち、「年年｛ねんねん｝」あるいは「年々｛ねんねん｝」と「年年｛としどし｝」とは品詞が違うだけでなく、意味も違うように思います。従って上記辞書の定義は十分でないように思います。
- 上記辞書に挙がっている例文も適切とは言い難いように思います。「**ねんねん**輸入が増加する」は問題ありませんが、「**としどしに**さびれてきた祭事」とは余り言わないように思います。「ねんねん」の意味として上記辞書が定義している文言に必要に応じて助詞の「に」を付けて副詞化した文言を使って、「**年を追うごとに**さびれてきた祭事」あるいは「**ねんねん**さびれてきた祭事」のような表現の方が一般的であるように思います。特に最後の「**ねんねん**さびれてきた祭事」が自然に聞こえるのは、一般に「さびれる」あるいは「衰退」というのは「年毎｛としごと｝」に変わる現象ではなく、長い期間一定の傾向がある現象ですので、「**としどしに**さびれる」という表現は例文として適していないと判断できます。

## English

**年年{ねんねん}** or **年々｛ねんねん｝**
- 庭に植えた木は**年々{ねんねん}** 大きくなっています。*The trees planted in the garden are gradually growing year by year*.
- 庭に植えたバラは**年々{ねんねん}** きれいな花を咲かせます。 *Roses planted in the garden bloom beautifully every year*.
**年年{ねんねん}** あるいは **年々｛ねんねん｝** は、「毎年徐々に」、あるいは、「毎年のように」のように、毎年状態が一定である、あるいは一定の傾向であるような意味で扱う時に使う。**ねんねん** *is used when treating every year in a meaning that the state is constant every year or the tendency of change is constant like "like every year" or "gradually year by year" or It is used such as year by year; annually; ​gradually year by year*.

**年年｛としどし｝**
- 庭に植えたバラは**年年{としどし}で**花の咲き具合が違います。*The roses planted in the garden bloom differently depending on the year.*　
**年年｛としどし｝** は、各々の年が特徴ある個別のものであるとして扱う時に使う。**としどし** *is used when treating each year as having a distinctive feature*.

---

## EDIT

"年々｛ねんねん｝ or 年々｛ねんねん｝" and "年年｛としどし｝" use the same kanji, but there are some difference between them.

- "ねんねん" has almost similar meaning to "毎年｛まいとし｝ *every year*" or "年｛とし｝が進｛すす｝むごとに *every time the year advances*", and even if they are replaced with each other, there is not much difference in meaning. On the other hand, "としどし" has almost similar meaning to "年毎｛としごと｝*each year*", and I think that the meaning does not change much even they are replaced with each other.
- As it is written in the dictionary introduced by Chocolate, "ねんねん" and "としどし" are different in "品詞｛ひんし｝ *part of speech*". "ねんねん" is an adverb and can be used as it is in sentences. On the other hand, "としどし" is a noun and it can be used for the first time in a sentence after attaching a particle such as "としどし**に**", "としどし**で**" or "としどし**の**". The same can be said to the similarly words with "毎年{まいとし} for ねんねん" and "年毎{としごと} for としどし" listed above. That is, "毎年{まいとし} " is an adverb and can be used as it is in sentences, and "年毎｛としごと｝" can be used only after adding a particle such as "としごと**に**", "としごと**で**" or "としごと**の**".
- When you compare the meanings of the two words written in the above dictionary, it should be said that if you add a particle to "としどし" and make expressions like "としどし**に**" or "としどし**で**", they become adverbs in the same meaning as "ねんねん".
  So it also should be said that the adverb made from "としどし" and the adverb "ねんねん" could be interchangeable.
  But thinking in the actual examples that we usually use, I think that the meaning of the sentence containing the above adverbs is considerably different from each other as is written in the example sentences in my original answer, therefore I think they cannot be interchangeable.
  The difference between the two is not only different in part of speech, but also in meaning.
  So I think that the definition of the above dictionary is insufficient.
- I think that the example sentence of the above dictionary is also inadequate. Looking at the example sentences, there is no problem with "ねんねん輸入が増加する", but I think we don't say much like "**としどしに**さびれてきた祭事". Instead we would say like "**年を追うごとに**さびれてきた祭事" or "**ねんねん**さびれてきた祭事" that are made from using the definitions of "年年｛としどし｝".