# 年々 is 【ねんねん】here, right?

Tags: word-choice, readings, reduplication

Someone else already asked here

[How do you read these kanji 年々?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/53971/31150)

(I am just making sure that I understood.)

In the following sentence, 年々 is read【ねんねん】, correct?

> 小学校入学【しょうがっこうにゅうがく】を控【ひか】える子【こ】どもたちのランドセル選【えら】びが、年々【ねんねん】過熱【かねつ】しています

> *The selection of school bags for children about to enter elementary school is becoming more and more heated every year.*

https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASQ6S62NTQ69DIFI00D.html?iref=comtop_Opinion_01

Comment: へ～　うちの近所の小学生はみんなランリュックですわ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is ねんねん.

As an additional comment, ねんねん is the more common in the first place. And you can most probably always read 年々 as ねんねん if it is not followed by particles.

A example of 年々{としどし} is like:

- 収入はその年年で変わる The income changes each year.

which could be 収入は年年{としどし}変わる with some elements dropped.

Generally ねんねん is used when referring to monotone change (usually increase/decrease) whereas としどし is for fluctuations. Possibly comparable to English *year by year* vs *from year to year*.